# PHP email attachments have still 0 kb

Tags: php, email, email-attachments

For some reason my PHP mail script constantly sends attachments as 0 kb despite I am paying attention to correct number of empty lines as was told in many similar answers around Stackoverflow.

Basically, they said there that "...supposed to be a blank line between the attachment header and the attachment contents" which I guess I got right - or not?.

But maybe I am missing something else here - can anyone tell me what is wrong with the code, that is: why it sends email attachments as of size 0 kb still?

This is the important part of the script:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['name']); $i++){
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
        $fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
    }
}

// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
$files = $fname;

$msg = '<b>E-mail:</b> some@email.here<br>';
$msg .= 'Some other text here...<br>';
$msg .= '<br><br><br>';

// boundary
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$message .= $msg . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    
// preparing attachments
for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
        
    $file = fopen($files[$i], "rb");
    $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$i]));
    fclose($file);
    
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"}; name=\"$files[$i]\"\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$files[$i]\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $data."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n\r\n";
}

// send
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "ok";
}
```

**UPDATE:**

So, the actual problem was in the 1st for() loop, where instead of "$fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];" it should be "$fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];", as that was producing just the name instead of the full path to the file, therefore my files was alwyas 0kb. That said, this works:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['name']); $i++){
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
        $fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
    }
}

// array with filenames to be sent as attachment
$files = $fname;

$msg = '<b>E-mail:</b> some@email.here<br>';
$msg .= 'Some other text here...<br>';
$msg .= '<br><br><br>';

// boundary
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$message .= $msg . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    
// preparing attachments
for($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++){
        
    $file = fopen($files[$i], "rb");
    $data = fread($file, filesize($files[$i]));
    fclose($file);
    
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"}; name=\"$files[$i]\"\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$files[$i]\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $data."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n\r\n";
}

// send
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "ok";
}
```

**BUT NOW ANOTHER PROBLEM:** now files have correct size but instead have wrong names without any extension - how to solve this? Should I define new variable just for the file names or could they be somehow taken from the $fname?

**UPDATE 2:**

So far I've managed to make it work, but only partially in the sense that only the 1st file in attachment is shown as it should but any other file is shown as long text full of letters and numbers - why? This is the script that partially work for me so far:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['name']); $i++){
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
        $fpath[] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
    }
}

$msg = '<b>E-mail:</b> some@email.here<br>';
$msg .= 'Some other text here...<br>';
$msg .= '<br><br><br>';

// boundary
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$message .= $msg . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    
// preparing attachments
for($i = 0; $i < count($fpath); $i++){
        
    $file = fopen($fpath[$i], "rb");
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fpath[$i]));
    fclose($file);
    
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"}; name=\"$fpath[$i]\"\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname[$i]\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $data."\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\r\n\r\n";
}

// send
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "ok";
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not use any library like Symfony Mailer or PHPMailer? Crafting such an email is not that simple and such libraries take the heavy part away from you

Comment: Sorry, but what kind of response is this??? Unbelievable, this helps a lot,. really - thank you!

Comment: They're correct; essentially everyone uses a library for this, because hand-building emails like this is complicated and prone to problems. Symfony's Mailer is a de-facto standard in the PHP world of 2023. Look how easy it could be: https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#file-attachments

Comment: My brief reading of the spec states that the final boundary must have two hyphens at the end, and you don't seen to have this anywhere. Also, is it correct that you define the boundary on a separate line to the `Content-type` header? Again, the example I'm looking at has that on the same line.

Comment: I am trying to find possible ridiculously small problem, like missed line or something that I might not see but others can, and you suggesting me to completely change everything using some sort of external library which I do not need, all works except the problem I described. I DO NOT WANT TO USE ANOTHER LIBRARY, just to find where the problem with the attachment section in my shown script lies!

Comment: @droopsnoot thank you - at least some reasonable and useful comment that aims me at the problem, I will look at it

Comment: @droopsnoot "Also, is it correct that you define the boundary on a separate line to the Content-type header? Again, the example I'm looking at has that on the same line. " - sorry, but where in that code is any boundary defined at the same line as Content-type header? What I see is they are on their own line...? There are 3 lines with "Content-Type" but none of them contains boundary: does not that "\r\n" at the end of the line make it to new line?

Comment: Even if installing the library might be a bigger task than fixing a single hyphen or line feed, through using any library, your self-written code will become much shorter, and extending the mail sending functions with more stuff is so much easier

Comment: Still that does not answer the problem/question being asked: what is wrong with the code shown above? Probably thing or two coded wrongly. What I am expecting still is someone who could take the code above, update it with the corrections and showed it as normal separate post/answer so I can set it as the correct answer - exactly what I see everywhere else on Stockoverflow, but for some reason all of you decided to preaching about stuff instead of the actual answer. Really, why on the other posts with basically exactly the same problem they do not have to deal with this kind of stuff I have to.

Comment: @droopsnoot so it turns out you were wrong too, at the end: no double hyphens are needed at the end, code works as is shown above...still I am thankful for your meaningful answer as it turns out you were the only one that actually helped at some point! Looks like I will have to answer my own question as it seems no one of those who know the answer is willing to answer it...nevermind as I am quite close already.

Comment: @fafa When I said "the example I'm looking at", I meant the example code I was looking at elsewhere when trying to see what your problem might have been. I am aware of what "\r\n" means, and my point was specifically that your code was different to what I had seen elsewhere. Seems as if it doesn't make any difference.  The spec _does_ say, though, that you should close the last boundary with double hyphens, as you have now done in your answer.

Comment: @droopsnoot how should I know you meant script from elsewhere and not the one shown in my post when we talk about the post of mine under the post of mine? Anyway, does not matter as it's solved already, I just want to point out the misunderstanding I got into as you didn't clarify you're talking about some other code form elsewhere. Still your 1st comment helped me a bit + that last doubled hyphened boundary I added was not present in at least half of those other codes on Stackoverflow - my original code came exactly from those examples yrs ago but somehow stoped work for me tho it was before.

Comment: I won't drag it out as you've solved the problem - but I said "the example I'm looking at has that code on the same line", so it clearly (to me at least) wasn't _your_ code I was referring to, I was contrasting the example code to the different way you had done it in your code.  Anyway, it's working for you now, so no point going over it.

Comment: to me exactly that was clear sign you are telling about my code pointing about a possible problem there, even more so when in the same response or sentence you also mentioned my code is lacking doubled hyphens...easy as that. I guess you should be much more clear next time to avoid these kind of misunderstanding, but as you said it is solved already, thus no problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again I had to come to the solution myself!
Well, it turned out to be problem of just 2 things:

- wrongly defined file path from files to be attached
- wrongly placed boundary section for attached files

This is the final correct code that works for me beautifully:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['filename']['name']); $i++){
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if (file_exists($tmp_name)){
        $fpath[] = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $fname[] = $_FILES['filename']['name'][$i];
    }
}

$msg = '<b>E-mail:</b> some@email.here<br>';
$msg .= 'Some other text here...<br>';
$msg .= '<br><br><br>';

// boundary
$semi_rand = md5(time());
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
    
$headers = "From: $from";
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n";
$headers .= " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n";
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
$message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
$message .= $msg;

// preparing attachments
for($i = 0; $i < count($fpath); $i++){
    
    $file = fopen($fpath[$i], "rb");
    $data = fread($file, filesize($fpath[$i]));
    fclose($file);
    
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    
    
    $message .= "\r\n--{$mime_boundary}\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"}; name=\"$fpath[$i]\"\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fname[$i]\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $data;
}

$message .= "\r\n--{$mime_boundary}--";

// send
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo "ok";
}
```